# In a React SPA without react-router, how can a parent component be rendered in a child component?

Tags: reactjs, components, parent-child, render

My very first question on Stack Overflow relates to Child-Parent communication with React and more specifically how to call a parent component and switch the current view to the parent-component-view. 
I understand that props are passed down from parent to children and that children can ask their parents to pass a prop by calling a parent’s method. 
But how do you call the entity parent component, not just a prop. The Child component calls the parent component to be rendered. The current view should disappear. 
Since components can be imported, there should be a way to just render them within an importer’s component.
I hope the following code illustrates my question.

```
import React from 'react';
import Parent from './parent';

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    this.changeView = this.changeView.bind(this);

    changeView() {
        return <Parent />;
    //or,  since we want to render:
    // React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('child-view');
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="child-view">
            <div className="list">
                // content that should not be seen anymore
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.changeView}>
        </div>
        )
    }
```